# Getting Form data with Flask

Tags: python, flask

When getting from data in Flask, can I somehow bind html elements and their values to an object without using Jinja templating.

Or do I have to send the data via a manual HTTP Post?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking, but have you looked at [`flask-wtf`](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)? It integrates the excellent [`wtforms` library](http://wtforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) with Flask, making form handling a bit less of a chore.

Comment: Yes i have but it seems you have to use Jinja templates for that

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I have a signup for my website. I want to be able to send that data either via a POST request, or by sometype of html databinding. 

However I do not want to use Jinja because it does not play nicely with bootstrap

Comment: Jinja has nothing to do with bootstrap - can you update your question with an example that highlights the problem you are facing?

Comment: bootstrap and jinja2 shouldn't conflict at all. It's probably you writing bad HTML, so bootstrap can really apply on it. And you can still use flask-wtf to display forms and get the data sent from the client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are really asking is "given a client-side JavaScript object, how can I serialize it so that I can easily access the data server-side".  If that is your question, there are two ways to do so:

1. The way you provided in your answer, serializing your object as JSON and submitting it as the body of your POST request:

   ```
   @app.route("/user", methods=("POST",))
   def save_user():
       data = request.get_json()
       # ... etc. ...
   ```
2. Using [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) on the client side:

   ```
   var yourUser = {
       firstname: "Joe",
       lastname: "Smith",
       email: "joe@smith.com",
       password: "12345"
   };

   var formData = new FormData();
   Object.keys(yourUser).forEach(function(key) {
       formData.append(key, yourUser[key]);
   });
   // Post formData back to your controller using XHR
   ```

   combined with the normal `request.form` access on the server side:

   ```
   @app.route("/user", methods=("POST",))
   def save_user():
       data = request.form
       # ... etc. ...
   ```

Comment: Hi, I was trying to upload a file through ajax(http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/uploading-files-ajax), then try to get data in the form. I have to set processData to false in ajax. However, the ImmutableMultiDict only contains `ImmutableMultiDict([('------WebKitFormBoundaryoQPpntEvtoR8exZF\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name', u'"paper_json"\r\n\r\n.......\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryoQPpntEvtoR8exZF--\r\n')])` the keys and values are messed. request.files returns nothing. Do you have any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solve the issue with this

```
@app.route('/post/user',methods=['POST','GET'])
def saveuser():
 data = json.loads(request.data)
 firstname = data['firstname']
 newuser = User(firstname,lastname,email,password)

 db.session.add(newuser)
 db.session.commit()
```

first I get the json string from request.data, then i parse it into a dict and save it to my db

Comment: Just FYI, `request` has a `get_json` method (or a `json` attribute pre-0.10) that will give you the equivalent of `json.loads`.  So you can do: `data = request.get_json()`.